# Jquery dynamic hide and show for drop down menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am having trouble making my drop down menu dynamically show blocks of html code which are labelled `style="display:none"`.

I have following code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(\'select[name="questiontype"]\').change(function(){

  if ($(this).val() == "multiple")
      alert("call the do something function on option multiple"); 
  else
      alert("call the do something function on option programming");
  });​
</script>

<form action="addQuestion.php" method="post">                       
  <select name="questiontype">                  
    <option name="questiontype" value="multiple" click="return showMultiple();">Multiple Choice< /option>    
    <option selected name="questiontype" value="programming" click="return showProgramming();">Programming< /option>                                
</select><br>

<input type="hidden" name="course" value="'.$course.'" />

<div id=\'multiple\' style="display:none">
   Multiple
</div>
<div id=\'programming\' style="display:none">
   Programming
</div>
</form>
```

i tried these functions to .show() the div's by id from the dropdown menu but no luck and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I also removed some code in the div id blocks to make it easier to read.

```
<script>
        function showMultiple(){
            $('#multiple').show();
            $('#programming').hide();
            return false;
        }
        function showProgramming(){
            $('#multiple').hide();
            $('#programming').show();
            return false;
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/crustyashish/wSW7z/)

**HTML**

```
<select id="selectMe">
    <option value="multiple">multiple</option>
    <option value="programming">Programming</option>
</select>
<br><br><br>

 <div id="multiple" class="group" >
   Multiple
</div>

 <div id="programming" class="group" >
   Programming
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.group').hide();
    $('#multiple').show();
    $('#selectMe').change(function () {
        $('.group').hide();
        $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
    })
});
```

Comment: This hides the div id="programming" block but the change function doesn't do anything for me

Comment: This JS assumes that #multiple will always the the one that is selected, ignoring html auto populate data or possible user set data. You will want to be careful statically setting the first div shown.

Comment: I mean when I select programming from the drop down menu nothing changes.

Comment: initially ur 1 div is always visible?

Comment: Sorry it works, thanks! I didn't notice you changed select name to select id

Comment: It actually works, but the data I pass to the dropdownlist is not showing when it was initially hidden then displayed. So the options were displayed, but when I hid the ddlist and show it again the options were gone. Some one can help thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your `select` `option` you are using `click` instead of `onclick` `event`

```
<select name="questiontype">                  
    <option name="questiontype" value="multiple" onclick="return showMultiple();">Multiple Choice</option>    
    <option selected name="questiontype" value="programming" onclick="return showProgramming();">Programming< /option>                                
</select>
```

And no need to use escape for single quotes,

```
<div id='multiple' style="display:none">
   Multiple
</div>
<div id='programming' style="display:none">
   Programming
</div>
```

and in `script` tag

```
$('select[name="questiontype"]').change(function(){
```

Comment: I had onclick before but it's still not showing. The reason I had them escaped was because this is all inside a php file.

Comment: even in php there is no need to escape

Comment: @Aris You would need to escape them in PHP, **if** you do something like `echo 'Sam\'s house';` otherwise the echo would end after the m.
@Garvin If you used echo with quotation marks instead of the apostrophe, this would work: `echo "Sam's house";`. Just wanted to clarify that for anyone reading this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form action="addQuestion.php" method="post">                       
            <select name="questiontype" id="questiontype">                  
                <option value="multiple">Multiple Choice</option>    
                <option selected value="programming">Programming</option>                                
            </select>

            <br>



            <div id='multiple' class="group" style="display:none">
                Multiple
            </div>
            <div id='programming' style="display:none"  class="group">
                Programming
            </div>
        </form>
```

Put this code in head section:

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">


            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.group').hide();
                $('#programming').show();


                $('#questiontype').change(function () {
                    $('.group').hide(1000);
                    $('#'+$(this).val()).show(1000);
                })
            });

        </script>
```