# php Foreach run only a limited time and insert data inside correct div

Tags: php, html

I want to pull a record from a web service and display it nicely inside a div, like in [this example](http://guillaumeperrault.com/dropdown/).

When someone selects "Number of days" it should filter the result.

This is what I have so far:

```
<script>
function itinerary(name)
{
    var last = document.getElementById(selected);
    selected = name;
    var current = document.getElementById(selected);

    last.style.display = "none";
    current.style.display = "";

    document.getElementById("selectItinerary").blur();
    }
</script>
<?php
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);

    $days = "http://services.gerbertours.com/tours.asmx/Days?type=2&cityID=1146";
    $ch1 = curl_init($days); 
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);       // make sure we get the response back 
    $xml1 = curl_exec($ch1);        // execute the post 
    curl_close($ch1);               // close our session 
    $var1 = simplexml_load_string($xml1);
    $configData1 = json_decode($var1, true);

    $days = 0;
    foreach ($configData1 as $key=>$val) {
        if ($val > $days) {
            $days = $val;
        }
    }
    //echo $days;

    //$days = "http://services.gerbertours.com/tours.asmx/Days?type=2&cityID=1146";
    $url = "http://services.gerbertours.com/tours.asmx/Sample?type=2&CityID=1146&days=$days";
    $ch = curl_init($url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);        // make sure we get the response back 
    $xml = curl_exec($ch);      // execute the post 
    curl_close($ch);                // close our session 
    $var = simplexml_load_string($xml);

    $configData = json_decode($var, true);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($configData);
echo '</pre>';

foreach ($configData as $row) {
    echo 'Day:' . $row['Day'].'<br>';
    echo 'Time:' .$row['Time'].'<br>';
    echo 'Description:' .$row['Description'].'<br>';
}

?>
    <select id="selectItinerary" onchange="itinerary(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value); this.blur" style="font-size:11px">

<?php
    for ($day = 1; $day <= $days; $day++) {
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $day; ?>"><?php echo $day; ?> Day Tour</option>
<?php

    }
?>
    </select>

<?php
    $dayCount = 1;
    foreach ($configData as $row) {
        $currentDay = $row['Day'];
        if($dayCount==$days);break;
?>

        <div id="<?php echo $dayCount; ?>" class="itinerary">
            <div class="day">
                <?php echo 'Day:' . $row['Day']; ?>
            </div>

            <div class="time">
                <?php echo 'Time:' .$row['Time']; ?>
            </div>

            <div class="description">
                <?php echo 'Description:' .$row['Description']; ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php 
        $dayCount++;
    }
?>
```

Everything else is going okay. All I need to do is to filter the result based on user selection, if for example someone selects "3 Day tour" it should show 3 items from the result. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using Jquery, you can show/hide elements using:

```
document.getElementById('elementId').style.display = 'block'; // to show
document.getElementById('elementId').style.display = 'none';
```

The idea is to hide all elements, then when the onchange event fires, you show the element you want to show. So in your code you just have to change

```
current.style.display = "";
```

to

```
current.style.display = "block";
```

I'd also put these before, so you hide all you need to hide before showing the required div:

```
document.getElementById('1').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('2').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('3').style.display = 'none';
```

But of course, for larger projects, I'd recommend [Jquery](https://jquery.com/) or any Javascript framework to make things easier. Check out: [Jquery dynamic hide and show for drop down menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395228/jquery-dynamic-hide-and-show-for-drop-down-menu)

Comment: Hello @aljo Thank you for your response I can update Jquery stuff without an issue currently I need to put data in correct div for example if Day 1 content should show inside div ID with 1

Comment: If they're not too many, you can generate all the divs for all the days, then just hide all of them. When your dropdown triggers onchange, you can show the relevant div.